Remove subsection head bar if title is empty in Beamer
I'm currently using Frankfurt theme with \useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars} to have subsection titles in the frame. However, I sometimes have no subsection titles. In this case I would like to remove the empty bar where the subsection title usually appear.
In other word, I want to have \useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars} when I have subsections and \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars} when the frame is no longer in a subsection.
I guess that I can not swith from true to false like this before a frame, so I wonder if I need to modify beamerouterinfolines.sty. In that case, how can I make a condition to see if the subsection title is empty or not ?

Please always include a compilable test file in your questions.

You could modify the headline like this:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty
    \csname beamer@sb@subsectionfalse\endcsname
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
       color(6ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
     }
   \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(frametitle.bg);%
       color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg);%
       color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)
     }    
  \else
    \csname beamer@sb@subsectiontrue\endcsname
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(subsection in head/foot.bg);%
      color(2.25ex)=(subsection in head/foot.bg);%
      color(3.25ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
      color(8.75ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(frametitle.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(subsection in head/foot.bg)
    }
  \fi
}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{sec 1}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}


